# No icons when installing QGIS

Tags: qgis, installation, qgis-3, windows, osgeo4w

I've been trying to install QGIS 3.4.4 Madeira on Windows 10 x64. I've tried the network installer and the standalone version, both of which say they installed successfully but no desktop or start menu items appear and I can't find any way to run the software.

There's no qgis.bat file in the bin folder, just a qgis.bat.tmpl. Renaming that as I saw someone suggest doesn't do anything.

Also saw a suggesting to remove qt5 files from the system32 folder but there aren't any of those files in there.

Any ideas what could be going wrong with the install?

Comment: Every package from OSGEO4W does a postinstall. Do do that the installer executes a batch file in %OSGEO4W_ROOT%\etc\postinstall. It seems, that it did not happen during your install.Try to install with administrator privilege or just execute the postinstall batch file for qgis with that privilege.

Comment: Tried running the postinstall.bat with admin privileges but just flashes up a window and there's no change.
No icons in a folder on the desktop by the way

Comment: Try to verify if nircmd.exe is see as PUA virus/malware from your antivirus, enable it and reinstall.

Answer (score 1):

Running `postinstall.bat` fixed the problem on QGIS 3.16.

Close QGIS and make sure it's not running on your PC.

1. Navigate to the following folder: `C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.16`
2. Rename `postinstall.bat.done` to `postinstall.bat`
3. Right click on `postinstall.bat` and "Run as Administrator".
4. Run QGIS and you should see the icon.